# What is the difference between the LTS version and the stable version of node.js?

Tags: node.js

What is the difference between the LTS version and the stable version of node.js ?

What version should we use on production ?

Comment: LTS=Long term support, which means that it has at least 18months support and maintenance. A stable version has only 6months support. Something like that. You should use LTS in production. https://nodejs.org/en/blog/community/node-v5/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It depends where you are using node.js in your apps and how sensitive are they.

**LTS** *(Long Term Support, currently v6.11.2)* - as was mentioned in the comment, will have support and maintenance for at least 18months. So its better to use this one in Production for node.js as a back-end service.

**Stable** *(currently v8.3.0)* - will have support for approximately 8months, with features/updates released more often. This version will be ok for Production if you're using node.js for fron-end services (dependency management etc.). Will work for node.js on back-end as well, if you have ability to easily update your apps without interrupting the environment.

**The reason of 2 type node.js versions:**

As node.js team described when they announced this feature is that 2 different types of node.js versions will meet your node.js needs. Basically, if you have a complex node.js app and you want stability, then stay on **LTS**. If you are able to update your app often, or you use node.js only for the fron-end tools, then use **Stable**. The philosophy is to push new features, performance updates, bug fixes etc. in a quick manner, so companies/developers who wants the 'on the edge' technology and loves node.js, will be able easily use it and expect updates every 2weeks.

Comment: Expanding on this, if you go to https://nodejs.org/en/, you'll see there are two versions of Node you can download, LTS and Stable