# Why Node.js 8 is recommended instead of Node.js 10?

Tags: node.js

Why Node.js 8 is *recommended for most users* (on official site) instead of Node.js 10? Is it possible something working in Node.js 8 will not work in Node.js 10 (some npm packages for example)? In which cases should I am to prefer this or that version? They both have LTS. The quote about Node.js 10 and LTS from [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/whats-new-in-node-10-ad360ae55ee4):

> Node 10 was released April 24, 2018 and will enter Long Term Support
>   (LTS) in October 2018

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the LTS version and the stable version of node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829167/what-is-the-difference-between-the-lts-version-and-the-stable-version-of-node-js)

Comment: Some npm libraries haven't caught up to v10. For example, any [native module](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) will need to be rewritten and recompiled to the latest specs.

Comment: @JoeClay, according my quote they both have LTS already. Am I right?

Comment: "according my quote they both have LTS already." – No, they don't. It's not October yet.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I can wait this three days. )))

Comment: The transition date has not been announced yet, and there is a guaranteed warning period between announcement and transition of at least 14 days. So, even if the announcement is made within the next three days, and the minimum warning period is used, you will have to wait at least 17 days.

Comment: Next month, Node 10 will become an active LTS version. Node 8 will continue to be an active LTS version for 6 months after that, at which point it will move to maintenance LTS (i.e. critical bugfixes only). At that point, support for Node 6 will end. See here for more info: https://github.com/nodejs/Release

Comment: @Vic, Are many modules not recompiled for 10?

Comment: So, guys LTS already is not argument a month later and I try to understand how actively existing modules are recompiling for 10?

Comment: @AndreyBushman Some native modules might fail to compile in later versions.